# java - Can JRE and compiler version affect the functionality of a Socket based connection?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets

I've been working on a client/server application for android(Using Eclipse 4.4, JRE 7 and Android-SDK Tools) and it works perfectly when using the server(as runnable jar) on my home PC and the client application on my android device.

However, I tried today to run the server on a friend's laptop, but we had to build the runnable jar file with his Eclipse 3.3. We had some compatibility issues, but we built it. Still, after running the server application I couldn't manage to connect the app on the device with the server on his laptop.

My question is: You think it had something to do with the different versions of the compilers used to build the applications (the server application and the client one being built by different compilers) or there was something else wrong there?
I was thinking the there might be some differences between the Socket related classes from the two versions of JRE.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, Eclipse, for starters, has the very bad idea to use its own compiler instead of the standard, bare-bones `javac`. Now, discrepancies may also arise from the fact that you use different major JDK versions...

Comment: No +fge, its compiler is a very good idea and does a number of useful things. That said, Eclipse 3.3 is very *old* version, but even then, it would generate code that runs correctly. It's more likely a networking issue (firewall?) on +laurGanta's friend's machine.